# Why do we need to run start when using net/http?

Tags: ruby, http, session, request

If I use:

```
uri = URI("...")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.read_timeout = 60
# Add http.start here? Why?
for i in 1..n
    uri = getFullUri()
    req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.path)
    resp = http.request(req)
end
```

everything works fine.

Why do I need to add an `http.start`?

I see that `http.started?` returns `false` everywhere if I don't add `http.start`, but does this have a negative impact?

Which is the difference between those 2 cases?

Do the number of TCP connections or HTTP sessions differ?

Comment: You would call `start` explicitly if you are going to make multiple HTTP `request`s within the same TCP connection (given that the server supports [persistent connections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection))

Answer (score 1):

`http.start()` will explicitly open the TCP connection at the point in time that it's been called.  It's automatically called by `http.request()` if it hasn't been called already.  To wit, here's the first few lines of the `request` method:

```
def request(req, body = nil, &block)  # :yield: +response+
  unless started?
    start {
      req['connection'] ||= 'close'
      return request(req, body, &block)
    }
  end
```

Assuming `getFullUri()` takes less than a couple of seconds to run (see the `keep_alive_timeout` attribute), the original connection should be reused regardless of how it was created.

Comment: `start` is called with a block here, so the connection will be closed afterwards.